# How to delete a column for all rows in Hbase table

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, delete-row

We have 100k rows in a hbase table with 3 columns( all in the same column family). I need to delete the third column for all the rows?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible ways for you. Re-consider 'third column' requirement and use bulk delete or move to server side processing. I recommend to re-think your request before going further. Here are key points that should help:

- Definitely you are about to use `Delete` requests if you try to stay in client API scope.
- If you need to delete significant amount of specific column entries, the only way you can use (as for my current knowledge) is [bulk delete](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#delete(java.util.List)).
- In HBase there is no explicit definition of 'third column' for mutations like 'Delete'. You can specify only qualifier. Do you really need 'third' or do you know what qualifier your column has?
- If you really need some specific 'third party' delete condition, you need coprocessors, specifically endpoints. [Here is basic explanation](https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/coprocessor_introduction).
- Here is [question which should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618980/efficient-way-to-delete-multiple-rows-in-hbase), especially reference to BulkDeleteProtocol. It allows you to base delete on `Scan` request so you may need something [like this](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/coprocessor/example/BulkDeleteProtocol.html) but again with specific filtering.
- To achieve 'third column' filter over `Scan` you need something like [ColumnPaginationFilter](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ColumnPaginationFilter.html).

So your task is not so trivial but I'd recommend to look into the direction of endpoint with `BulkDeleteProtocol` based on `Scan` with filtering on `ColumnPaginationFilter`. Must warn I had no usage of this combination despite its components are well known.